# formatting double and float once and for all in jsf2 application

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, floating

I do a lof of manipulations, calculs with numbers (especialy double (#0.00) )

and I ask if is there a way to format those numbers once and for all 
I use this converter for the momentfor each double :

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#0.00" );
double d = 122.00;
System.out.println(df2.format(d));
double dou = new Double(df2.format(d)).doubleValue();
System.out.println(dou);
```

Output:

```
122.00
122.0
```

If you want two digits even its zero after decimal print it as `String`. `double` value of 122.00 is 12.0.If you assign `double dd = 122.00` and print it  will give output `122.0`

Comment: it return string bud I want double

Comment: I want two digit after comma always even if is 0